# Instead of Image, previous video (AVPlayer) is showing up in in UIImageView in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, video-streaming, avplayer

I need your help in feeding image/video on my app. I am using AVPlayer for displaying videos.

I am facing problem in displaying images once video is displayed, the previous videos are displaying on the upcoming images.

Here is my code. The image Url in **userPostImageStr** is correct but still it is showing last video.

```
if (userPostVideo != (NSString *)[NSNull null])
{
   AVPlayerViewController *playerViewController = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc] init];

    AVPlayer *player = [[AVPlayer alloc] init];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:userPostVideo];

    AVURLAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset assetWithURL:url];

    AVPlayerItem *item = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:asset];

    player = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithPlayerItem:item];

    playerViewController.player = player;

    [playerViewController.view setFrame:cell.userPostImage.frame];

    playerViewController.showsPlaybackControls = NO;

    [cell.userPostImage addSubview:playerViewController.view];

    [player play];
}

else if (userPostImageStr != (NSString *)[NSNull null])
{
    if (userPostImageStr != (NSString *)[NSNull null])
    {
        [cell.userPostImage setShowActivityIndicatorView:YES];
        [cell.userPostImage setIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];

        [cell.userPostImage sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:userPostImageStr]
                          placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"appIcon"] options: SDWebImageRefreshCached
                                 completed:^(UIImage image, NSError error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL)
         {

             if (image.size.width < cell.contentView.frame.size.width)
             {
                 // NEED to write the for contraint update at runtime
                 //[postImageView setConstraintConstant:image.size.width forAttribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth];
             }

         }];
    }
}
else
{
    cell.userPostImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"appIcon"];
}
```

Please reply if anybody aware of this problem.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are adding a subview containing the player to the cell without ever removing the subview. That's what's happening when you call

```
[cell.userPostImage addSubview:playerViewController.view];
```

When the cell gets reused, the views that have been added previously **are still there** and causing all sorts of unexpected behavior.

Before you add a subview, you should remove the existing view by calling

```
[theViewToBeRemoved removeFromSuperView];
```

This requires you to keep a reference to the view. One way is by setting the tag on the view. For example:

```
// Set the tag on the view.
playerViewController.view.tag = 1000;

// Remove the view with the matching tag.
[[cell.userPostImage viewWithTag:1000] removeFromSuperView];
```

I would also recommend having the player be a property in your cell subclass to keep everything organized.

Comment: The problem is occurring when the control is going in "else" part i.e. while displaying image but not video. 
Also, I had tried this. But still I am facing the same issue.

Comment: I see. If you carefully trace through the view hierarchy of each cell, I’m sure you'll be able to track down the problem. You just need to make sure all the views that are supposed to be there are present. If there are views that are not supposed to be there, then you will have to identify where they are coming from.

Comment: Hmmm... ok
Thank You @Daniel for your time.